# duplicating a dynamic element size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I am creating a website with react js that includes a number of images. What I would like to do is include some standard background divs / rectangles that are the exact same size of each related image so that those images can do some animations on top of them. Please see the below snippet. However I am not sure how to dynamically tell css what is the correct size of each image for it to duplicate. I've been playing around with creating a second exact image and then creating some sort of overlapped, inlet border, but it doesn't keep the same dimensions of the image. How best can I create a background rectangle that will always be the same size as the image I provide it? Thanks!

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      onClik: false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick()  {
    this.setState({onClick: !this.state.onClcik });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="parent-div">
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me!</button>
       <div className="child-div">
        <img className={this.state.onClick ? "on" : "off"} src="https://imgflip.com/s/meme/Cute-Cat.jpg" />
        <div className="background-div"></div>
       </div>
       <div className="child-div">
        <img className={this.state.onClick ? "on" : "off"} src="http://www.readersdigest.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/4-ways-cheer-up-depressed-cat.jpg" />
      <div className="background-div"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
img {
  width: 25%;
}

.on {
  transform: translateX(90px);
}

.background-div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that was what you were looking for but the divs are the same size as the images.

See updated code below:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            onClick: false
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({ onClick: !this.state.onClick });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="parent-div">
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me!</button>
                <div className="child-div">
                    <img className={this.state.onClick ? "on" : "off"} src="https://imgflip.com/s/meme/Cute-Cat.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div className="child-div">
                    <img className={this.state.onClick ? "on" : "off"} src="http://www.readersdigest.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/4-ways-cheer-up-depressed-cat.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
img {
  width: 25%;
}


.on {
  transform: translateX(80px);
}

.child-div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

.child-div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.child-div:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```